# Picking 3 cards, there is replacement and order matters

Tags: probability

Out of 52 cards I need to figure out how many possibly combinations there are if only 3 are selected. Everytime a card is selected, it is placed back into the deck and shuffled again, so there is replacement. Would there be 1/52 chance for each card everytime, so would the answer be (1/52)*(1/52)*(1/52)?

Comment: The **number** of possible sequences is $52^3$.  You answered correctly a different but related question, what is the probability of any particular sequence.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to figure the number of possibilities, it is of course not a fractional number.

But the number of possibilities is $52^3$ and the probability for some combination is $\frac{1}{52^3}$.